# Automate build and developement pattern with VisualStudio

Tags: version-control, build-automation, development-environment

I'm currently working on a project that's been going on for several years straight. The development-team is small (less than 5 programmers), and source-control is virtually non-existent, and the deployment-process as is is just based on manually moving files from one server to another. The project is in classic ASP, so building isn't an issue, as both deployment and testing is just about getting the files to where they need to be and directing the browser at the correct location. Currently all development is done on a network-drive which is also the test-server. The test-server is only available when inside the the local network (can be accessed trough vpn), and is available on the address 'site.test' in the browser (requires editing to the hosts-file on all the clients, but since there are so few of us that hasn't proven to be any problem at all). All development is done in visual studio. Whenever a file is change the developer that changed the file is required to write the file he changed into a word-document and include a small description as of what was changed and why. Then, whenever there's supposed to be a version-bump (deployment), our lead-developer goes trough the word-document and copies every file (file by file) that has changed over to the production-server. Now, I don't think I need to tell you that this method is very error prone (a developer might for instance forget to add that he changed some dependency, and that might cause problems when deployed), and there's a lot of work involved with deploying.

And here comes the main question. I've been asked by the lead developer to use some time and see if I can come up with a simple solution that can simplify and automate the "version-control" and the deployment. Now, the important thing is that it's **as easy as posible** to use for the developers. Two of the existing developers have worked with computers for a long time, and are pretty stuck up in their routines, so for instance changing it into something like git bash wouldn't work at all. Don't get me wrong, I love git, but the first time one of them got a merge-conflict they wouldn't know what to do at all. Also, it would be ideal to change to a more distributed development-process where the developers wouldn't need to be logged into vpn (or need internet at all) to develop, and the changes they made offline could be synced up when they were done with them. Now, I've looked at Teem Development Server from Microsoft because of it's strong integration with Visual Studio. As far as I've tested it seems possible to make Visual Studio prompt the user if they want to check in changes whenever the user closes Visual Studio. Now, using TFS for source-control would probably eliminate most of the problems with the development, but how about deployment? Not to mention versioning? As far as I've understood (I've only looked briefly at TFS), TFS has a running number for every check-in, but is it possible to tell TFS that this check-in should be version 2.0.1 of the system (for example), and then have it deploy it to the web-server? And another problem, the whole solution consists of about 10 directories with hundreds of files in, though the system itself (without images and such) is only 5 directories, and only these 5 should be deployed to the server, is this possible to automate?

I know there's a lot of questions here, but what is most important is that I want to automate the development process (not the coding, but the managing of the code), and the deployment process, and I want to make it **as simple as possible to use**. I don't care if the setup is a bit of work, cause I got enough time at hand to setup whatever system that fits our needs, but **the other devs should not have to do a lot of setup**. If all of the machines that should use the system needs to be setup once, that's no problem at all, cause I can do that, but there shouldn't bee any need to do config and setups as we go.

Now, do any of you have any suggestions to what systems to use/how to use them, in order to simplify the described processes above? I've worked with several types of scm-systems before (GIT, HG and SubVersion), but I don't have any experience with build-systems at all (if that is needed). Articles, and discussion on how to efficiently setup systems like this would be greatly appreciated. In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty subjective territory, but I think you need to get some easy wins first.  The developers who are "stuck up in there ways" are the main roadblock here.  They are going to see change as disruptive and not worth it.  You need to slowly and carefully go for the easy wins.

First, TFS is probably not going to be a good choice.  It's expensive, heavy, and the source control in TFS is pretty lousy.  Go for Subversion: it's easy to setup and easy to use, and it's free.  Get that in place first, and get the devs using it.  Much easier said than done.

Later (possibly much later), once the devs are using it and couldn't imagine life without a VCS, then you could switch to Hg or Git if you need first class branching and all those other nice features.

Once you have Subversion in place, you can use something like JetBrains TeamCity or Jenkins, both of which are free and easy to use.  However, I'm just assuming you don't have a lot of tests and build scripts that the CI server is really going to be running, so it's far more important that you get VCS first.  In all things: keep it as simple as possible.  Baby steps.  Get some wins, build trust, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I can't even begin to think where to begin with this!  Intending no offense directed at you, apart from the mention of git and HG, this post could have been written 10 years ago.

1) Source control - How can a team of developers possibly work effectively without *some* form of source control?  Hell, even if it's Visual Source Safe (* shudder *) at least it would be something.  You have to insist that the team implement source control.  You know what's available so I won't get into preaching about that.  (However, Subversion with TortoiseSVN has worked quite well for me.)

2)

> "write the file he changed into a
>   word-document and include a small
>   description as of what was changed and
>   why"

You have got to be kidding... What happens if two developers change the same file?  Does the lead then have to manually merge two changes that s/he extracts from the word doc?  Please see #1 and explain to them how commit comments work.

---

Since your don't really need to "build" (i.e. compiled, etc.) anything, you should be able to solve most of your problems with some simple tools.  First and foremost you need to use a source control solution.  Yes, the developers would have to learn how to use another tool (EEEK!).  You could do the initial leg work of getting the code into the repository.  If you have file access to the other developers machines, you could even copy a checked-out working copy to their machines so they wouldn't have to do the checkout themselves (not really that hard).  You could then use all the creamy goodness of version control to create version branches when each deployment needs to be done.  You could write simple scripts using the command line SVN tools to check out said branches and automatically copy the files to the target server(s).  Using a tool like BeyondCompare, the copy process could be restricted to only the files that are different (plus BC can handle an FTP target if that is an issue).  By enforcing commit comments on the SVN repo, you'll guarantee that the developers provide comments, and for each set of changes between releases you could very easily generate a list of all those comments using the CSM log retrieval features.

Comment: As everyone works on one server, rather than local copies, merging hasn't really been an issue. Other than that, thanks for the info.